# C# Regex matched, but not writing values

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have such regex, but it is matched, but it is not adding my values. Why is that?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Lab) (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+) (?<C5>\S+) (?<C6>\S+) (?<C7>.+))$");
```

Here is my text example:

```
Lab restart int(3) 4332 Range success (Var:4.344-1)
```

At the end I want to put my  and so on to my var. I do it like this.

```
Param0 = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
Param1 = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
Param2 = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
Param3 = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
Param4 = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
Param5 = match.Groups["C5"].ToString();
Param6 = match.Groups["C6"].ToString();
Param7 = match.Groups["C7"].ToString();
```

`Param0`, `Param1` and rest are still empty. But they are not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is your `match.Success = false`. The input string doesn't get matched by the reg expression. Try removing the last group:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Lab) (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+) (?<C5>\S+) (?<C6>\S+))$");

Param0 = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
Param1 = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
Param2 = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
Param3 = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
Param4 = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
Param5 = match.Groups["C5"].ToString();
Param6 = match.Groups["C6"].ToString();
```

You should use the `match.Success` to check if the match is successful first.

Comment: Of course you are right. I didn't notice that I added too many fields in regex. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regex you could just split by space

```
var myString = "Lab restart int(3) 4332 Range success (Var:4.344-1)"
var split = myString.Split(" ");
```

Then you will have all the parameters in the array of strings, your regex is just splitting by spaces anyway.

The problem with your regex is that the last group must be there, and currently you don't have that, in that case the regex should look more like this:

```
"(?<C0>Lab) (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+) (?<C5>\S+) (?<C6>\S+)(?: (?<C7>.+))?"
```

By adding the parenthesis around the space and your capture group, and then adding `?` at the end, the last group becomes optional.

Comment: good point, however he may want to add more criteria later. And this one also has to check the first string if it is `"Lab"` or not.

Comment: you could just subsequently check `if(split[0] == "Lab")`, which in my oppinion is easier to understand than a regex for most people.

Comment: There is still another case in which the input string has more than 2 continuous spaces, the regex solution won't match it but this will give the correct result. However it's the OP's problem.

Comment: @KingKing Correct, but with the information available, i think spliting the string is a more reasonable approach, even if i do like regexes a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As "King King" said, your regex is incorrect.  Here's a working example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Lab) (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+) (?<C5>\S+) (?<C6>\S+))$");
string s = "Lab restart int(3) 4332 Range success (Var:4.344-1)";
Match match = regex.Match(s);

string Param0 = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
string Param1 = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
string Param2 = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
string Param3 = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
string Param4 = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
string Param5 = match.Groups["C5"].ToString();
string Param6 = match.Groups["C6"].ToString();

Console.Write(Param0 + "\r\n"
            + Param1 + "\r\n"
            + Param2 + "\r\n"
            + Param3 + "\r\n"
            + Param4 + "\r\n"
            + Param5 + "\r\n"
            + Param6 + "\r\n"
            );
```

The output is:

```
Lab
restart
int(3)
4332
Range
success
(Var:4.344-1)
```

Comment: In your example you have 8 parameters, Param7 (C7) doesnt exist in your regex.

Comment: @FRoZeN Good catch, fixed now. Ta